# calcular los retardos de un empleado con jframe form

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

estoy haciendo un nomina básica de trabajadores, mi duda es como puedo hace que cada 3 retardos sea una falta y al mimo tiempo le descuente un día de salario ya que solo me falta sacar los retardos. disculparme, soy nuevo en esta pagina de ayuda

```
double salario = 0,salneto = 0,faltad=0,retards = 0;
String empleados = empleado.getText();
String puestos = puesto.getSelectedItem().toString();
int faltas = Integer.parseInt(falta.getValue().toString());
int retardos = Integer.parseInt(retardo.getValue().toString());

if(puestos.equals("Limpieza")){
  salario=266.6;
  salneto = 7 * salario;     

if(faltas>=1){
    faltad=faltas * 266.6;
   salneto=salneto-faltad; 
}
 if(retardos>=3){
    retards=266;

 salneto=salneto-faltad;
}   
dato.setText("nombre del empleado:"+empleados
               +"\n"+empleados
               +"\n"+puestos
               +"\n"+faltas
               +"\n"+retardos
               +"\n"+salneto);
}
```